# Запрос на добавление\извлечени данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: postgresql, sql

Добрый день. Имитирую отношение многие ко многим за счет доп. таблицы. Псевдокод:

```
Здание
---------
id serial
имя text

Расположение
---------
id serial
название text

Здание-Расположение
--------
id sedial
здание integer references Здание (id)
расположение integer references Расположение (id)
```

Проблема в том, что я нуб в SQL. Вопрос в следующем. Как мне правильно заполнять и извлекать данные? Сейчас я все делаю через несколько запросов. Возможно ли добавить или извлекать данные сразу по всем таблицам? Если да, приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

Данные добавляются только в одну таблицу.
Т.е. вам нужно сначала добавить данные в таблицы Задание и Расположение (в любом порядке), а потом в Здание-Расположение, чтобы не возникала ошибка ограничения по внешнему ключу.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Здание
INNER JOIN Здание-Расположение ON Здание-Расположение.здание = Здание.ID
INNER JOIN Расположение ON Расположение.id = Здание-Расположение.Расположение
```

Смотря что надо получить INNER JOIN можно поменять на LEFT OUTER JOIN